# How to remove only some network services on Mac?

Tags: macos, command

I noticed that on my Network I have thousands of useless services and I want to remove them, but I want to remove only these starting with "SAMSUNG".

When I run: 
**`% networksetup -listallnetworkservices`**

I get:

```
SAMSUNG Modem 1
...
SAMSUNG Modem 1392
Wi-Fi
LGE Android Phone 2
iPhone
Bluetooth PAN
Thunderbolt Bridge
```

As you can see I have more than on thousand of services starting with "SAMSUNG" and I want to remove only them.

[image]

When I trey to remove one of them: 
**`% networksetup -removenetworkservice "SAMSUNG Modem 4"`**

I just can't because of this error:

**You cannot remove SAMSUNG Modem 4 because there aren't any other network services on SAMSUNG Modem.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.**

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 3):

Solved by executing the following bash script:

```
/usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep "SAMSUNG Modem" | while read -r line
do
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -deletepppoeservice "${line}"
    printf 'Deleted %s\n' "${line}"
done
```

Decided not to touch `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`, not sure if the connection should not be deleted elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently and the solution is very simple

this file contains all network adapters /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

> this command list all samsung modems: ***networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep "SAMSUNG Modem"***
>
> this command remove one samsung modem (where X is a modem number, ex: "SAMSUNG Modem 155"): ***networksetup -deletepppoeservice "SAMSUNG Modem X"***

To remove all Samsung Modems do it on terminal:

```
for service in $(/usr/sbin/networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep "SAMSUNG Modem" ); do
    /usr/sbin/networksetup -deletepppoeservice "${service}"
done
```

Comment: I solved with this solution ``$ services=("${(@f)$(networksetup -listallnetworkservices | grep "SAMSUNG Modem" | sed s/\*//)}")
$ for service in $services[@]; do networksetup -deletepppoeservice $service; done``

Comment: List words instead of lines

Comment: Can you please explain better your problem? If the script is only listing words and not removing interfaces, Try Saving the code in my comment as .sh file, change permissions with "chmod +X you_saved_script.sh" and run as "bash your_saved_script.sh". I put the last command on my .bash_profile, and after boot, the system removes all interfaces. Working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

wish there was a more easy way...but nothing...

i stumbled upon your same issue...

Anyway...you can solve this issue cleaning this file

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

And by cleaning i mean: "remove the networkservice you don't need"

## UPDATE

I just emptied that file (ofc i did a backup before), opened network in setting and was totally empty (ofc). so i just added a new Position and named "Automatic" and now all works like a charm without the thousand of network bogus services

Have a good day

Antonio

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I checked this file and it has 209292 lines and I don't feel confident enough to empty it.
It had to be another an easier way to clear these useless Network data.